# not able to update local branch with master

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I created new branch: `private/feature` from bit bucket `master branch` and fetched it to my local using `git fetch origin`.

Now I'm done with my changes but I see there is some sync issue between my local branch and master branch i.e some changes are present in master and not in my local which is causing compilation issues in sdk.

I tried - `git pull origin master branch` , Already up-to-date

but now I see Your branch is ahead of 'origin/private/feature' by 373 commits.

I also tried :

```
git stash 
Git pull
git stash pop
```

but still same issue

What's the best approach for these kinda issues ?

Comment: You’re on a branch. `git rebase origin/master`. You’ll then need to force push up - it sounds like you’re history has already diverted from the remote in either case

Comment: Without push , do we have any other solution? Sd my changes aren't ready yet

Comment: You only need to push to share. That said, you _should_ push regularly to a remote branch - it's good practice. You can name "your" copy of the branch anything you want!

Comment: Did git rebase origin/master and then push , now did git pull origin but still my branch does not have latest changes , hence it gives compilation errors. Git status shows already uptodate.

Answer (score 0):

With **git fetch** do not combine changes into your actual branch.

You need to use since your branch private/feature:
**git merge origin master** or **git rebase origin master** for bringging changes of master branch.